# 2010 Chevy Malibu

Tags: chevrolet, malibu

My center brake light worked with no problems, but then I had my brakes changed and now the center brake light now works sporadically.  What could be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a separate fault that just happened to occur now.

If the other brake lights are functioning correctly, then the fault lies with either the wiring to that lamp, a loose connection in the wiring or an internal fault in the lamp.

If the other brake lights also mess around, check the switch and wiring.

Edit : as GdD has pointed out, the only common point is the brake pedal, the rest of the systems are separate.

Comment: Agreed. Brake lights are on a completely different system from the brakes themselves, the only thing they have in common is the brake pedal. When you push down on the pedal a sensor detects it and activates the tail lights.

Comment: @GdD good point, borrowed part of your comment!

Comment: Borrow away @SolarMike. Not sure it the malibu has the 3rd light on the trunk lid, if so the most likely point of failure's the wiring loom that goes up one of the lid arms.